# Why my button is possible to click only if cursor position is in content or in the border

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have problem with my button style. And when the cursor is in the button is can't click (if is not in the content or in the border of the element.

My xaml code:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource DataButton}" Content="OK" Command="{Binding OKButton}" MinWidth="72" Height="22" Margin="5" />
```

My static resource

```
<Style x:Key="DataButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#d6d6d6" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I fix this the user can click on button whatever is in the button perimeter.

Comment: Do you really need - <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />. Try removing this and check.

Comment: Is working yeah, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  `<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />` from the code. As you have replaced the built in style of Button, it no longer recognizes the click action defined in the Theme.

Answer (score 0):

You have overrided default style and set Alignment to Center. You can remove overrideDefaultStyle or remove alignment, or you can make your layout in the other way.